# How to get an observable of button states in RxJs?

Tags: rxjs

I have following observables:

```
mouseOver$      // fired when mouse enters button
mouseOut$       // fired when mouse leaves button
mouseDown$      // fired when mouse button is pressed (over button)
globalMouseUp$  // fired when mouse button is released (anywhere)
```

What I would like to achive is the following:

```
mouseOver: state changes to 'hover'
mouseOut: state changes to 'normal'
mouseDown: state changes to 'active'
gloalMouseUp: state changes to 'normal'
```

The catch:

If the state is `active` (mousebutton is down) and the mouse leaves the button, the state should change to `normal`. When the mouse re-enters the button again wihtout releasing the mousebutton the state should be `active`. If the mousebutton was released while outside the button, the state should be `hover`.

I just can't figure this out without relying on a separate state variable to hold the 'active' state.

Answer (score 0):

Already got it

```
let active$ = merge(
  mouseDown$.pipe(map(() => true)),
  globalMouseUp$.pipe(map(() => false))
).pipe(startWith(false));

let hover$ = merge(
  mouseOver$.pipe(map(() => true)),
  mouseOut$.pipe(map(() => false))
);

let state$ = combineLatest(active$, hover$).pipe(
  map(([active, hover]) => hover ? (active ? 'active' : 'hover') : 'normal')
)
```